# Any possibility that I can provide configuration details at run time to producer and consumer in spring-kafka?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We are migrating our project to microservices using spring boot. I have a requirement where I should be able to run producer and consumer using the configuration details such as bootstrap servers and key-value serdes provided by the user at run-time.

I was able to do this using java Apache Kafka API in the earlier project but I don't see any way to do this using spring-kafka API as it allows to define the producer or consumer related configuration only via Spring java configuration class or application.properties.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to opt for spring-kafka instead of using your existing apache kafka api ?

Comment: The whole application including other modules is getting migrated to spring boot. I am exploring if I can utilize spring boot kafka API here, instead of Apache kafka API ?

Comment: yes, you can definitely explore spring-kafka, but personally, I use Apache Kafka api's just to be more independent and decoupling.

Answer (score 1):

You can override whatever properties you want at runtime for both consumers and producers.

Use the `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` to create the listener container:

```java
@Autowired
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory;

...

    ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = factory.createContainer("someTopic");
    container.getContainerProperties()
            .getKafkaConsumerProperties()
            .setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "...");
    ...
    container.getContainerProperties().setMessageListener(someListener);
    container.start();
```

On the producer side, use this constructor:

```java
/**
 * Create an instance using the supplied producer factory and properties, with
 * autoFlush false. If the configOverrides is not null or empty, a new
 * {@link DefaultKafkaProducerFactory} will be created with merged producer properties
 * with the overrides being applied after the supplied factory's properties.
 * @param producerFactory the producer factory.
 * @param configOverrides producer configuration properties to override.
 * @since 2.5
 */
public KafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<K, V> producerFactory, @Nullable Map<String, Object> configOverrides) {
    this(producerFactory, false, configOverrides);
}
```

Comment: Hi Gary. Thanks for the response.

Can you throw some light on this ?

Just wanted to be sure, if new producers or consumers can be created, started or stopped on demand at runtime after the spring boot application is started.

Comment: Yes, of course, use the code above to create and start a new container or template and `stop()` the container and `destroy()` the template (to close its producer) when you no longer need them.