# Multiple kafka producers and consumers with different configuration details with spring-kafka

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We have an API that connects to multiple kafka topics to produce and consume kafka messages. We use spring-kafka and apart from the topic name (which can be provided at runtime for both consumers and producers), we have another property that is different per topic (the encryption key for serializing/deserializing kafka messages) which raise the issue that we cannot reuse the same kafka producer/ kafka consumer configuration for all topics.

The initial approach that we came with is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    private final KafkaProperties properties;

    @Bean(name = TOPIC_1_PRODUCER)
    public KafkaTemplate<String, GenericRecord> kafkaTemplateTopic1() {
        Map<String, Object> producerProps = properties.buildProducerProperties();
        producerProps.put(ENCRYPTION_KEY, "encryption_key_for_topic_1");
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerProps));
    }

    @Bean(name = TOPIC_2_PRODUCER)
    public KafkaTemplate<String, GenericRecord> kafkaTemplateTopic2() {
        Map<String, Object> producerProps = properties.buildProducerProperties();
        producerProps.put(ENCRYPTION_KEY, "encryption_key_for_topic_2");
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerProps));
    }

    @Bean(name = TOPIC_3_PRODUCER)
    public KafkaTemplate<String, GenericRecord> kafkaTemplateTopic3() {
        Map<String, Object> producerProps = properties.buildProducerProperties();
        producerProps.put(ENCRYPTION_KEY, "encryption_key_for_topic_3");
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerProps));
    }
}
```

With this approach, we will need a new KafkaTemplate bean for every new topic where we need to produce messages, so basically one kafka template per topic and the associated kafkaTemplate bean will be injected in the service designed to produce the kafka messages for that particular topic.

The 2nd approach would be to use only one KafkaTemplate bean (one kafka producer) and provide the encryption key at runtime. For this one I had a look at [Any possibility that I can provide configuration details at run time to producer and consumer in spring-kafka?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67688992/any-possibility-that-i-can-provide-configuration-details-at-run-time-to-producer) and came with the below implementation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    private final KafkaProperties properties;

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, GenericRecord> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> producerProps = properties.buildProducerProperties();
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerProps);
    }
    
}
```

And the publisher service:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KafkaProducer {

    private final ProducerFactory<String, GenericRecord> producerFactory;
    private final TopicResolver topicResolver;

    public void sendMessage(GenericRecord genericRecord) {
        TopicInfo topicInfo = topicResolver.resolve(genericRecord);

        Map<String, Object> configOverrides = new HashMap<>();
        configOverrides.put(ENCRYPTION_KEY, "encryption_key_for_resolved_topic");
        KafkaTemplate<String, GenericRecord> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory, configOverrides);

        ProducerRecord<String, GenericRecord> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(topicInfo.getTopicName(), genericRecord);
        ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, GenericRecord>> listenableFuture = kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord);
        listenableFuture.addCallback(new KafkaSendCallback<String, GenericRecord>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, GenericRecord> result) {
                log.info("Kafka message successfully sent");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull KafkaProducerException ex) {
                log.error("Kafka message failed to be sent with error {}", ex.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

By using this approach, **a new KafkaTemplate instance** will be created for each message produced, which I guess is not framework intended and I don't know how this could affect kafka **performance** overall.

What is your view between the 2 approaches presented? Is there any other possible solution to provide the configuration at runtime while using one KakaTemplate bean/one kafka producer?

We have the same need on the consumer side.

Comment: How exactly are you calculating "encryption_key_for_resolved_topic"? Is this some database lookup? A Hashmap? Why cannot this function store its own cache of created templates, rather than make the same template repeatedly for the same topic/key pair? Otherwise, I'm not sure I understand how this question is unique to Spring ; you'd have the same issue with plain KafkaProducer... You could also use a ProducerInterceptor for the key, but it's not clear from the example how the serializer uses that config you've added

Comment: On the other side, yes, you can use the same consumer, since each consumer record has a topic field, and the deserializer also has access to the topic name, so your decryption logic could be placed there, and conditionally triggered by any topic name, such as making remote calls to some keystore, or pulling from a cache for previously seen topic names

Comment: You can use a single `KafkaTemplate` configured with a `DelegatingByTopicSerializer`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single `KafkaTemplate` configured with a `DelegatingByTopicSerializer`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#by-topic

```java
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<Integer, Object> producerFactory(Map<String, Object> config) {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config,
            new IntegerSerializer(),
            new DelegatingByTopicSerializer(Map.of(
                    Pattern.compile("topic[0-4]"), new ByteArraySerializer(),
                    Pattern.compile("topic[5-9]"), new StringSerializer())),
                    new JsonSerializer<Object>());  // default
}
```

Comment: By using the proposed approach with `DelegatingByTopicSerializer`, I am still not able to provide a different encryption key per topic, as the config map that holds the `KafkaProperties` is unique. Any idea how can we provide a different encryption key per topic in this approach?

Comment: You can configure each delegate yourself with different properties and tell the producer factory not to configure the DBTS with the common properties. There’s a constructor parameter for that. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/878448e952d22cc61c46ce2ae50a547e1a064f20/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/core/DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java#L243